# How to drag positioned widget inside a stack widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm creating an application in which the user can drag his text over an image and can generate that image. I can drag text widget over an image, but the problem is that the text goes out of the screen if we drag it to the end in any direction(top, left, bottom, right). And I want that if the text is larger and the user drags it to the right, it will arrange it to the next line automatically.

This is the feature that I want. Please visit [memegenerator](https://imgflip.com/memegenerator),

***Code***

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DesignScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String formData;

  const DesignScreen({Key? key, required this.formData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DesignScreen> createState() => _DesignScreenState();
}

class _DesignScreenState extends State<DesignScreen> {
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Design"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/oneIO.jpg",
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: _offset.dy,
                  left: _offset.dx,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    child: Text(widget.formData),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              setState(() {
                _offset = Offset(_offset.dx + details.delta.dx,
                    _offset.dy + details.delta.dy);
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They go out-of-screen because their `top` and `left` properties are either too small or too large. You can use `clamp` function to limit the offset to a range. For example:

```
  Positioned(
    top: _offset.dy.clamp(0, 200),
    left: _offset.dx.clamp(0, 200),
    child: ...
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and attention. This works for top and left values, but how can bound text widget from right and bottom as well?

Comment: Based on your needs, you need to do some calculations. To get the total screen size, you can use `MediaQuery`, to get available space during layout, see `LayoutBuilder`. For "right" limit, you need to calculate the "upper limit" for `left` property: `total width - text width`.